# Regular Expression c# special treatment when delimiter exists or doesn't exists

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression in c#: `"(.+?)(\\[3\\]|$)"`.

It divides a string into one or more substrings when the delimiter looks like `[3]`.

For example the sentence: *"The sun,[3]is rising[3]again"*

Will give me 3 Matches with -

1. "The sun,"
2. "is rising"
3. "again"

I want to extend this expression so that it will return the whole string if no matches are found.

Thanks

Comment: Your regex already does what you want, you just need to look at the first captured group of each match rather than the match as a whole. If you can explain why this is not sufficient, someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why that complicated? Just do something along these lines:

```
if RegEx.IsMatch(...)
{
    // return string array
}
else
{
    // return entire string
}
```

HTH Thomas

Btw.: Your Regex formats badly in HTML...

Comment: I have good reason to do that, it simplified my program logic, so It needs to be in the regex pattern....Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You need Customized regular express please check the sites link below for customize regular expressions and most famous regular expressions

1. For testing the expression   http://regexpal.com/
2. Software for Regular Expressions http://www.regular-expressions.info/
3. Library for regular expression http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Hope these links will help you to guide and find your required regular expression

Comment: The regexpal tester is powered by JavaScript, but the OP is using the .NET flavor.  It's best to use a tester that works  the same flavor as you are.  There can be huge differences between flavors, mostly in terms of the features they support.  That's certainly the case between JavaScript vs. .NET.